# Summing value of Column A for each distinct value of Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table below, let's call it "Sales". For each distinct "Motion" value in this table, I would like the corresponding "Quantity" values to be summated into one row. The "SaleID" value is not relevant here.

```
SaleID        EngineType    Motion        Quantity
1             E1            L             5
2             E1            L             3
3             E1            L             3
4             E1            L             1
5             E1            L             3
6             E1            L             7
7             E1            V             5
8             E1            V             4
9             E1            V             5
10            E1            V             5
```

What I want is something like this:

```
EngineType    Motion        Quantity
E1            L             22
E1            V             19
```

What query do I need to generate this table?

Comment: _"The "SaleID" value is not relevant here"_ How can it not be when it _appears in the expected result_?

Comment: Sorry, I just copy-pasted the rows from the first table and forgot to remove it. Fixed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select max(SaleID),EngineType,Motion,sum(Quantity) from table
group by EngineType,Motion
```

Comment: This should be `SUM(Quantity) as Quantity` and the `max(SalesID)` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

select enginetype, motion, sum(quantity) from sales group by enginetype, motion